# Laravel New Project - Permission Denied

Tags: laravel, permissions

I am trying to setup a new Laravel site and I am running into an issue I have never had such problems with before. When loading up my site, I get the error:

```
The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I have edited the file permissions to 775. I don't know what else to do!

Comment: you must be check `/var/www/html/storage/logs/` folder exists in your project

Comment: @davit it exists!

Comment: You checked in your local project or remote??

Comment: I'm looking in the FTP onto the server. I only have this project in one place right now. Just working on getting the server setup.

Comment: Not yet. I am just connected to the server with an ftp. I'm just trying to get the site working before exporting to git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the owner of the folder:

```
chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change your project folder permission

Comment: and all inside folder?

Comment: Yup! I checked all the folders they all have 775

Answer (score 0):

> The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

This error basically happens when in your project absent `../storage/logs` folder. Firstly you must be check this folder exists in your project. If does not exist this folder add it and inside it `.gitignore` file.
  **/storage/logs/.gitignore**

```
*
!.gitignore
```

Comment: This folder does exist with the .gitignore file in it already